# How to make this web architecture (div inside div) only using document.createElement in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question. How can I make this DOM architecture using javascript document.createElement()

```
<div class="load-wrapper">
 <div class="inner-load"></div>
 <div class="middle-load"></div>
 <div class="outer-load"></div>
</div>
```

I knew that we can use `document.createElement("div")` and `document.addClassList("load-wrapper")`, but I am quite confused, how to make the architecture above.

If you ask why I want to make it using `javascript`, the reason is that I want to make a loader in vue mounting but using `js` since we using `microfrontend`, it easier to use the same way in `js`, instead of making it using the new component. can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: You're missing a few `</div>` tags

Comment: You can also assign the whole `div` to the variable and then append it to your HTML easily.

Comment: @CertainPerformance ups, sorry my bad, thankyou for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it using only [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). You can use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```js
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.className = 'load-wrapper';
document.body.appendChild(wrapper);

const inner = document.createElement('div');
inner.className = 'inner-load';
wrapper.appendChild(inner);

const middle = document.createElement('div');
middle.className = 'middle-load';
wrapper.appendChild(middle);

const outer = document.createElement('div');
outer.className = 'outer-load';
wrapper.appendChild(outer);
```

Or [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```js
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.className = 'load-wrapper';
wrapper.innerHTML = `
 <div class="inner-load"></div>
 <div class="middle-load"></div>
 <div class="outer-load"></div>
`;
document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it works in me,  but can I ask one more thing? between the first way and the second way, which is better? for now I choose the second one since it easy to read, but for the performance, is it affect something?

Comment: @RakishFrisky, I don't know which one is more performant; If you run the code once per frame or action, you'll never notice a difference. The first approach is safer in general because when you deal with an HTML code, you risk an XSS vulnerability.